# PHP upload file turns animated gif into regular image after upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

I have found this upload script online and everything works perfectly.

There is just one thing that I cant figure out myself, that is that whenever I upload an animated GIF image it stops animating and turns to a regular image with the extention GIF.

This is the upload file.

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
############ Edit settings ##############
$ThumbSquareSize        = 150; //Thumbnail will be 200x200
$BigImageMaxSize        = 800; //Image Maximum height or width
$ThumbPrefix            = "thumb_"; //Normal thumb Prefix
$DestinationDirectory   = '../images/uploads/'; 

  //specify upload directory ends with      / (slash)
$Quality                = 90; //jpeg quality
##########################################

//check if this is an ajax request
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){
    die();
}

// check $_FILES['ImageFile'] not empty
if(!isset($_FILES['ImageFile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']))
{
        die('Something wrong with uploaded file, something missing!'); // output error when above checks fail.
}

// Get the $_POST image tag 
if(isset($_POST['tag']))
{
    $tt = secure($_POST['tag']);
    $tag = str_replace(' ','',$tt);
}else{
    $tag = 'no-tag';
}

// Get the $_POST image title 
if(isset($_POST['img_title']))
{
    $img_title = secure($_POST['img_title']);
}else{
    $img_title = NULL;
}

// Random number will be added after image name
$RandomNumber   = random_str(35);

$ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['ImageFile']['name'])); //get image name
$ImageSize      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['size']; // get original image size
$TempSrc        = $_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']; // Temp name of image file stored in PHP tmp folder
$ImageType      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type']; //get file type, returns "image/png", image/jpeg, text/plain etc.

//Let's check allowed $ImageType, we use PHP SWITCH statement here
switch(strtolower($ImageType))
{
    case 'image/png':
        //Create a new image from file 
        $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
        break;          
    case 'image/jpeg':
    case 'image/pjpeg':
        $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    default:
        die('Unsupported File!'); //output error and exit
}

//PHP getimagesize() function returns height/width from image file stored in PHP tmp folder.
//Get first two values from image, width and height. 
//list assign svalues to $CurWidth,$CurHeight
list($CurWidth,$CurHeight)=getimagesize($TempSrc);

//Get file extension from Image name, this will be added after random name
$ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
$ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);

//remove extension from filename
$ImageName      = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName); 

//Construct a new name with random number and extension.
$NewImageName = $RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt;

//set the Destination Image
$thumb_DestRandImageName    = $DestinationDirectory.$ThumbPrefix.$NewImageName; //Thumbnail name with destination directory
$DestRandImageName          = $DestinationDirectory.$NewImageName; // Image with destination directory

//Resize image to Specified Size by calling resizeImage function.
if(resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$BigImageMaxSize,$DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType))
{
    //Create a square Thumbnail right after, this time we are using cropImage() function
    if(!cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$ThumbSquareSize,$thumb_DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType))
        {
            echo 'Error Creating thumbnail';
        }
    /*
    We have succesfully resized and created thumbnail image
    We can now output image to user's browser or store information in the database
    */
    echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td align="center"><img src="/images/uploads/'.$ThumbPrefix.$NewImageName.'" alt="Thumbnail"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';


    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO pics (user_id,img_id,img_url, img_url_s, img_tag, img_title, date) VALUES ('".$user['id']."','".$RandomNumber."','/images/uploads/".$NewImageName."','".str_replace('..','',$thumb_DestRandImageName)."', '".secure($tag)."','".secure($img_title)."',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");


}else{
    die('Resize Error'); //output error
}
 }


// This function will proportionally resize image 
 function     resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$MaxSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$ImageType)
{
//Check Image size is not 0
if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0) 
{
    return false;
}

//Construct a proportional size of new image
$ImageScale         = min($MaxSize/$CurWidth, $MaxSize/$CurHeight); 
$NewWidth           = ceil($ImageScale*$CurWidth);
$NewHeight          = ceil($ImageScale*$CurHeight);
$NewCanves          = imagecreatetruecolor($NewWidth, $NewHeight);

// Resize Image
if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $CurWidth, $CurHeight))
{
    switch(strtolower($ImageType))
    {
        case 'image/png':
            imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            imagegif($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
            break;          
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,$Quality);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
//Destroy image, frees memory   
if(is_resource($NewCanves)) {imagedestroy($NewCanves);} 
return true;
}

}

//This function corps image to create exact square images, no matter what its original   size!
 function cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$iSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$ImageType)
{    
//Check Image size is not 0
if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0) 
{
    return false;
}

//abeautifulsite.net has excellent article about "Cropping an Image to Make Square bit.ly/1gTwXW9
if($CurWidth>$CurHeight)
{
    $y_offset = 0;
    $x_offset = ($CurWidth - $CurHeight) / 2;
    $square_size    = $CurWidth - ($x_offset * 2);
}else{
    $x_offset = 0;
    $y_offset = ($CurHeight - $CurWidth) / 2;
    $square_size = $CurHeight - ($y_offset * 2);
}

$NewCanves  = imagecreatetruecolor($iSize, $iSize); 
if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, $x_offset, $y_offset, $iSize, $iSize, $square_size, $square_size))
{
    switch(strtolower($ImageType))
    {
        case 'image/png':
            imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            imagegif($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
            break;          
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,$Quality);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
//Destroy image, frees memory   
if(is_resource($NewCanves)) {imagedestroy($NewCanves);} 
return true;

}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GD can't handle gifs by default.I recommend using WideImage, it's really simple to use and used in an OO fashion.

Answer (score 2):

GD cannot handle animated GIFs. You will need to use a different library such as ImageMagick, which is unfortunately considerably harder to use than GD...

Comment: To bad, thank you anyway and also for the fast replay.